# Spring boot bean initialization order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot for developing a simple REST API but i'm stuck with spring's order to initialize beans of my application . how can i control the order of beans initialization in my application ?

i'm using spring boot 2.1.7  the problem is that spring tries to initialize  ContactRestController  before SomeService  which ContactRestController    depends upon  so it ends up with the  NullPointerException at the constructor of ContactRestController      :

```
@RestController
public class ContactRestController {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService ;
   // no-args constructor 

    public ContactRestControlle(){
       this.someService.doStuff() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `@PostConstruct` annotation for this situation (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy)

Comment: This is *precisely* the kind of reason that constructor injection is better than field injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `SomeService` as parameter to constructor, and remove `@Autowired` from field. Now it's impossible for it to be null.

Alternatively, move the code in the constructor to a `@PostConstruct` method.

You should read [Running Setup Data on Startup in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring). The guide starts by listing your code as an example of how not to do it.

Comment: thank you very much  , the constructor injection  worked very well .